# Apex SOQL Query fails once org-wide sharing set to private

Tags: apex

I've made some "snapshots" in our custom object (Funding Source) that shows relevant fields from Account and other custom objects (Personal Guarantor and Equipment) on the same record page as our custom object.

It worked great before we were forced to change our org-wide sharing to Private (unfortunately it has to remain private). I've since added the appropriate sharing between roles/profiles, but have not been able to get it to work again.

I've also changed the class to without sharing hoping that would yield the desired outcome. But it did not.

Here is an example of the code for Equipment Object:

```
public without sharing class DS_EQinFundingSource {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Equipment__c> getEQs(Id fsId) {
        // Querying the Related_Opportunity__c field directly in a single query
        Funding_Source__c fs = [SELECT Id, Related_Opportunity__c, Related_Opportunity__r.AccountId
                                FROM Funding_Source__c WHERE Id = :fsId];

        // Checking if the fs record and the related opportunity are not null
        if (fs != null && fs.Related_Opportunity__c != null) {
            Id oppId = fs.Related_Opportunity__c;

            // Querying the Account object directly
            return [SELECT Id, Name, Condition__c, Price__c, Equipment_Code_Description__c
                    FROM Equipment__c WHERE Opportunity_Name__c = :oppId];
        }

        return new List<Equipment__c>(); // Return an empty list if no records are found
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright- Not sure how this fixed it, but I'll take the W.

I had to give the profile access to the apex classes in Apex Class Access. This was not required when the org wide settings were read/write for the objects involved, but once we changed to private on involved objects, somehow this made all the difference.